# Unknown column error using eclipselink jpa

Tags: java, spring, jpa, orm

I am using JPA eclipse link with spring to find a data in the database based on a string. I have implemented a method

```
@Transactional
    public String authorization(LL l){
        Query query = m.createNativeQuery("SELECT a FROM user a WHERE a.name = ?");
        query.setParameter(1, l.getName());
        UserEntity tmp = (UserEntity) query.getSingleResult();
}
```

My database is simple

```
id | name | password
```

However, by executing this I get error

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown
>   column 'a' in 'field list'

I have read the documentation and this should be the right way ho to execute such query. Why is this throwing said error? Did I make mistake or did I overlook something?

All help is appreciated.

Comment: That is not SQL. It is JPQL

Answer (score 1):

You seem to expect to have an entity as a result, so instead of a native query:

```
m.createNativeQuery
```

use the

```
m.createQuery
```

**Update**

In case you need to use native query you should add the expected result class:

```
Query query = m.createNativeQuery("SELECT a.* FROM user a WHERE a.name = ?", UserEntity.class);
```

Comment: using createQuery throws "user" is not mapped error cuz im not using hibernate

Comment: then you have to add the result class as the second param.. you may have to play with aliases in the select cluase to get proper names